# Something we are good at

Tags: synonyms

What’s the word to describe that everyone’s good at something? I recently conversed with someone from America and she used a word beginning with ‘S’ it’s bothering me that I can’t remember the word. She said everyone has ***

Many thanks

Comment: skills? Everyone has enough skills to succeed at that something?

Comment: Thank you. The word wasn’t ‘skills’. It was more like everyone has a talent or something they’re good at.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your first sentence. I thought it meant everyone is good at the same thing, but I think you mean everyone is good at at least something. Would it be "strength," as in "everyone has their own strengths?"

Comment: Possibly "*everyone is special*", popularised by the show *The Incredibles*, but that has other connotations.

Comment: I guess you are loking for shrewdness

Comment: Thank you everyone. Appreciate your efforts. I think it was some slang the lady had used. Is there a word streak, strife, streak something with S. Apologies

Comment: It wouldn't be either of those.

Comment: @user310988 See my answer! The sound of "streak" and "strife" jogged my mind!

Comment: You're welcome! Remember to accept your favorite answer by clicking the check-mark next to it! Have a good one!

Comment: Not "expert" by any chance?

Comment: Savvy? ..........

Answer (score 1):

**Sleight** [slahyt]

noun

1. skill; dexterity.
2. an artifice; stratagem.
3. cunning; craft.

(dictionary.com)

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sleight

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has *strengths*

As in:

> Talents, knowledge, and skills -- along with the time spent (i.e.,
>   investment) practicing, developing your skills, and building your
>   knowledge base -- combine to create your strengths.

[Source](http://www.strengthsquest.com/help/general/143096/difference-talent-strength.aspx)